# If I have a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, what is the next valid subnet mask address

Tags: subnet, netmask

If I have a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, what is the next valid subnet mask address on either side (above or below)

Comment: How do you define "next subnet mask"? /25 or /23? Anyway, that's your answer.

Answer (score 7):

255.255.255.0 is 0b11111111.0b11111111.0b11111111.0.

One wider, 0b11111111.0b11111111.0b11111110.0, is 255.255.254.0.

One narrower, 0b11111111.0b11111111.0b11111111.0b10000000, is 255.255.255.128.